# What IQueryable.Provider.CreateQuery<T> will provide?

Tags: c#, serialization, lambda, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

I want to create something like remote Linq expression executor with EF core 2.

At first, user send a request to the server

2) server will generate an expression which can be execute on user demand

something like: `{value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable1[X.API.NewsPaper]).Where(model => (model.Id.ToString() == "630b7340-068e-47be-ba0e-2e03bdd72e1e")).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault().Posts}`

Then server will serialize it by `Aq.ExpressionJsonSerializer` and it will put it into its response (note: Generated expression can be different due to client request and database scheme so I don't know anything about database so I can not use a predefined expression)

3) Client will request to execute generated expression by sending it to the server

4) Server will try to deserialize it by my custom function of `Aq.ExpressionJsonSerializer` library

and the problem will appear here:

after deserializing the expression, I can not execute any function on it.

Here is my custom `Aq.ExpressionJsonSerializer` function

```
namespace Aq.ExpressionJsonSerializer {
    partial class Deserializer {
        private ConstantExpression ConstantExpression (
            ExpressionType nodeType, System.Type type, JObject obj) {
            object value;

            var valueTok = this.Prop (obj, "value");
            if (valueTok == null || valueTok.Type == JTokenType.Null) {
                value = null;
            } else {
                var valueObj = (JObject) valueTok;
                var valueType = this.Prop (valueObj, "type", this.Type);

                if (typeof(IQueryable).IsAssignableFrom(valueType)) {
                    value = this.queryableProvider.GetIQueryableByType(valueType.GetGenericArguments().FirstOrDefault());
                } else {
                    value = this.Deserialize (this.Prop (valueObj, "value"), valueType);
                }
            }

            switch (nodeType) {
                case ExpressionType.Constant:
                    return Expr.Constant (value, type);
                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException ();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the interface implementation:

```
public IQueryable GetIQueryableByType (Type type) {
    ExpressionQueryableType = type;
    return this.GetType ()
        .GetMethod (nameof (GetIQueryable))
        .MakeGenericMethod (type)
        .Invoke (this, null) as IQueryable;
}

public IQueryable<T> GetIQueryable<T> () where T : class =>
    dbContext.Set<T> ().Select (x => x);
```

Here is my Controller code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PagedListExp (Cursor cursor) {
    var defaultSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
        MaxDepth = 15,
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
    };
    defaultSettings.Converters.Add (new ExpressionJsonConverter (Assembly.GetAssembly (typeof (MyController)), this));
    var path = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Expression> (cursor.ExpressionPath, defaultSettings);

    var queryable =
        this.GetType ()
        .GetMethod (nameof (GetIQueryableFromExpression))
        .MakeGenericMethod (ExpressionQueryableType, modelParser.GetResourceType(cursor.IssuedFor))
        .Invoke (this, new object[] { path }) 
       // as IQueryable<dynamic>;
        as IQueryable<Post>

    var size = queryable.Count();

    ...

}

public IQueryable<TTarget> GetIQueryableFromExpression<TSource, TTarget> (Expression exp) where TSource : class {
    return dbContext.Set<TSource> ().AsQueryable<TSource> ().Provider.CreateQuery<TTarget> (exp);
}
```

And here is the error message:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[X.API.Post]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[X.API.Post]' of method 'Int32 Count[Post](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[X.API.Post])'
Parameter name: arg0

System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateOneArgument(MethodBase method, ExpressionType nodeKind, Expression arguments, ParameterInfo pi, string methodParamName, string argumentParamName, int index)
```

Thanks

Comment: Can I ask the obvious question why you send a serialized expression up and down while the server (seemingly) may as well return the results directly?

Comment: This is a part of my general server [link](github.com/MohammadJamali/NeutronGeneralAPI) which will act as a library, in this scenario for each icollection in models, NGAPI will generate a card list which can be navigated by a cursor, this action can be apply to any icollection in any depth with any path, path will be extracted in a recursive function which generate the query, one card list can be in X->Y->Z next one can be X->Y->Z->T and so on. so I have 2 options: first, get initial request, generate expression, return result, second: save generated expression, load expression, return result

Comment: with this mechanism user can choose a card list and I will try to fetch next page for it

Comment: Looks like an over-complicated way to reinvent HATEOAS.

Comment: as I read in HATEOAS tutorial you have to specify link location with ...linkTo(methodOn(... but I do it automatically, however I have solved this problem...

Comment: @Mohammad If you have solved your question, you may post it here. Personally, I think it is an overkill to have a serialised expression.